# sorting a tcl dictionary inside txt file

Tags: csv, sorting, tcl

I need some help with writing a tcl code, to sort the data from a dictionary. The dictionary saves lists in a .txt file. I need to access the file and sort it through the second column of the lists.

```
1,0.8,bananas,,,,,
2,1.0,apples,,,,,
3,5.1,grapes,,,,,
4,2.4,oranges,,,,,
5,1.7,pineapples,,,,,
    ...
```

how can i sort that dict data, to look like that:

```
1,0.8,bananas,,,,,
2,1.0,apples,,,,,
5,1.7,pineapples,,,,,
4,2.4,oranges,,,,,
3,5.1,grapes,,,,,
    ...
```

please, can you help me making this sorting code?

i tried many codes, but with no sucess.

Comment: Have you written anything to read the file and populate a dict?

Comment: Can you show us something that you tried?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You appear to be seeking to sort CSV data by the floating point values in the second column. Is this correct?

Comment: Your are correct...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tcl's `lsort -command` option would be useful here.

To use it, first define a proc that takes two arguments (usually called a and b) which returns -1, 0, or 1.  Each pair of items in the list will be used as a pair of arguments to this proc.

```
set lines {
    1,0.8,bananas,,,,,
    2,1.0,apples,,,,,
    3,5.1,grapes,,,,,
    4,2.4,oranges,,,,,
    5,1.7,pineapples,,,,,
}

proc sort_by_col2 {a b} {
    set list_a [split $a ","]
    set list_b [split $b ","]

    set a2 [lindex $list_a 1]
    set b2 [lindex $list_b 1]

    if {$a2 < $b2} {
        return -1
    } elseif {$a2 > $b2} {
        return 1
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}

lsort -command sort_by_col2 $lines

--> 1,0.8,bananas,,,,, 
    2,1.0,apples,,,,, 
    5,1.7,pineapples,,,,, 
    4,2.4,oranges,,,,, 
    3,5.1,grapes,,,,,
```

Comment: hi Chris, thank you so much for you reply!!! many thanks for your help!! i will try today write in my code...

Comment: hey Chris, it worked fine...thank you for you help!!